# How to correct my wpm formula in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I am a learning student, Currently I am working on a typing website. I am using [codingartist](https://codingartistweb.com/2021/11/typing-test-with-html-css-javascript/) code as base. I have done some modification in this code. At the time variable I am taking value from user with the help of select option menu, so this is my time variable :

```
let time = parseInt(document.getElementById("time-select").value);
```

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Typing Test</title>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

                <div class="select">
                    <label for="time-select">Select time:</label>
                    <select id="time-select">
                        <option value="60">1 minute</option>
                        <option value="90" selected>1.5 minutes</option>
                        <option value="120">2 minutes</option>
                        <option value="300">5 minutes</option>
                        <option value="480">8 minutes</option>
                        <option value="600" >10 minutes</option>
                    </select>
                </div>


      <div class="stats">
        <p>Time: <span id="timer">0s</span></p>
        <p>Mistakes: <span id="mistakes">0</span></p>
      </div>
      <div
        id="quote"
        onmousedown="return false"
        onselectstart="return false"
      ></div>
      <textarea
        rows="3"
        id="quote-input"
        placeholder="Type here when the test starts.."
      ></textarea>
      <button id="start-test" onclick="startTest()">Start Test</button>
      <button id="stop-test" onclick="displayResult()">Stop Test</button>
      <div class="result">
        <h3>Result</h3>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <p>Accuracy: <span id="accuracy"></span></p>
          <p>Speed: <span id="wpm"></span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Script -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my index.js

```
//Random Quotes Api URL
const quoteApiUrl = "https://api.quotable.io/random?minLength=80&maxLength=100";
const quoteSection = document.getElementById("quote");
const userInput = document.getElementById("quote-input");
let quote = "";

let time = parseInt(document.getElementById("time-select").value);

let timer = "";
let mistakes = 0;



function updateTime() {
    // Get the new time value from the dropdown menu
    let time = parseInt(document.getElementById("time-select").value);
    // Update the timer display
    document.getElementById("timer").innerText = time + "s";
}
// Add an event listener to the dropdown menu to call the updateTime function when the value changes
document.getElementById("time-select").addEventListener("change", updateTime);




//Display random quotes
const renderNewQuote = async () => {
  //Fetch contents from url
  const response = await fetch(quoteApiUrl);

  //Store response
  let data = await response.json();

  //Access quote
  quote = data.content;

  //Array of characters in the quote
  let arr = quote.split("").map((value) => {
    //wrap the characters in a span tag
    return "<span class='quote-chars'>" + value + "</span>";
  });
  //join array for displaying
  quoteSection.innerHTML += arr.join("");
};

//Logic for comparing input words with quote
userInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
  let quoteChars = document.querySelectorAll(".quote-chars");
  //Create an arrat from received span tags
  quoteChars = Array.from(quoteChars);

  //array of user input characters
  let userInputChars = userInput.value.split("");

  //loop through each character in quote
  quoteChars.forEach((char, index) => {
    //Check if char(quote character) = userInputChars[index](input character)
    if (char.innerText == userInputChars[index]) {
      char.classList.add("success");
    }
    //If user hasn't entered anything or backspaced
    else if (userInputChars[index] == null) {
      //Remove class if any
      if (char.classList.contains("success")) {
        char.classList.remove("success");
      } else {
        char.classList.remove("fail");
      }
    }
    //If user enter wrong character
    else {
      //Checks if we alreasy have added fail class
      if (!char.classList.contains("fail")) {
        //increment and display mistakes
        mistakes += 1;
        char.classList.add("fail");
      }
      document.getElementById("mistakes").innerText = mistakes;
    }
    //Returns true if all the characters are entered correctly
    let check = quoteChars.every((element) => {
      return element.classList.contains("success");
    });
    //End test if all characters are correct
    if (check) {
      displayResult();
    }
  });
});

//Update Timer on screen
function updateTimer() {
  if (time == 0) {
    //End test if timer reaches 0
    displayResult();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerText = --time + "s";
  }
}

//Sets timer
const timeReduce = () => {
  time = parseInt(time);
  timer = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
};

//End Test
const displayResult = () => {
  //display result div
  document.querySelector(".result").style.display = "block";
  clearInterval(timer);
  document.getElementById("stop-test").style.display = "none";
  userInput.disabled = true;
  let timeTaken = 1;
  if (time != 0) {
    timeTaken = (60 - time) / 60;
  }
  document.getElementById("wpm").innerText =
    (userInput.value.length / 5 / timeTaken).toFixed(2) + " wpm";
  document.getElementById("accuracy").innerText =
    Math.round(
      ((userInput.value.length - mistakes) / userInput.value.length) * 100
    ) + " %";
};

//Start Test
const startTest = () => {
  mistakes = 0;
  timer = "";
  userInput.disabled = false;
  timeReduce();
  document.getElementById("start-test").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("stop-test").style.display = "block";
};

window.onload = () => {
  userInput.value = "";
  document.getElementById("start-test").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("stop-test").style.display = "none";
  userInput.disabled = true;
  renderNewQuote();
};
```

I am trying to create a typing test that measures the words per minute (WPM) of the user's input. However, the WPM calculation is not giving the correct results. When I test the code, the WPM value is always much higher or as same as word typed (even if i take 2min. for typing) than expected.

```
 let timeTaken = 1;
  if (time != 0) {
    timeTaken = (60 - time) / 60;
  }
  document.getElementById("wpm").innerText =
    (userInput.value.length / 5 / timeTaken).toFixed(2) + " wpm";
```

I know given code is wrong with 60 default value. so i tried this:

```
 let remainTime = time - parseInt(timer);
    let timeTaken = time - remainTime;
```

but it also gives doesn't give correct wpm value.

Comment: I was wondering why you have to divide `timeTaken` by 100. In my opinion you can simply divide it by 60.

Comment: Sorry for mistake but i also didn't work, i have tried possible to change the time taken.

Comment: Why is there a division by 5 in `userInput.value.length / 5 / timeTaken).toFixed(2) + " wpm"`? Is it guaranteed that all words are 5 characters long or the average length is 5?

Comment: According the my rules of a typing website a want 5 characters word as average

Comment: Can you try `timeTaken = time / 60;` instead ?

Comment: but how about if i stop the test in the middle of the test? then it will calculate whole time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I am sure that it will work as per my research:

```
let timerLengthInput = document.getElementById("time-select");
const timerLength = timerLengthInput.value;
let time = timerLength;
```

and write the in your displayResult-

```
 let timeTaken = 1;
    if (time !== 0) {
        timeTaken = (timerLength - time) / 60;
    }
 document.getElementById("wpm").innerText =
    (userInput.value.length / 5 / timeTaken).toFixed(2) + " wpm";
```

timeReduce function-

```
const timeReduce = () => {
  timer = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Mate. Can you collabrate with me in my team?

Comment: i am in. Check my profile there you will get my website and contacts